# Forces acting in a system (internal/external)

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, free-body-diagram

Consider a rocket taking off. It can be thought of two objects, a body and the ejected fuel. At some point in time (instantaneously) the mass of the body is $m$ and the mass of the fuel ejected is $M$, we know due to newtons 3rd law that the force extered on the fuel is equal and opposite to the force on the body, lets call that $F$, so taking both objects to be one system, the force acting on them is $F  -F - Mg - mg$, as the weights act downawards towards Earth, which equals $-(m+M)g$. As $F$<sub>net</sub> $= ma$, we have $-(m+M)g = (m+M)a$, leading to $a=-g$. Now what is this the acceleration of, the center of mass of the system? Taking each mass on its own the net forces would be $F - Mg$ and $mg + F$ respectively.

Comment: Yes, it is the acceleration of the centre of mass. There must be a duplicate for this question I think.

Comment: THANKS for the conformation I can close the question now.

Comment: In the absence of other external forces other than gravity, the combined center of mass is indeed under the influence of gravity and hence $a=-g$ is correct. The COM will free fall.